# Lazy loading of fields that are part of the main record

Tags: nhibernate, lazy-loading

I'm a relative newbie at NHibernate, so I'll beg forgiveness in advance if this a stupid question.  I've googled it and searched the documentation, and am getting all wrapped around the axle.

I'm maintaining/enhancing an existing application that uses NHibernate for a relatively straightforward table. The table has about 10-12 fields, and no foreign key relations. The table contains somewhere around a dozen or so rows, give or take.

Two of the fields are huge blobs (multi-megabytes).  As a result, the table is taking an excessive amount of time (4 minutes) to load when working with a remote DB.

The thing is that those two fields are not needed until a user selects one of the rows and begins to work on it, and then they are only needed for the one row that he selects.

This seems like exactly what lazy loading was meant for.  I just can't quite figure out how to apply it unless I break up the existing DB schema and put those columns in their own table with one-to-one mapping, which I don't want to.

If it matters, the program is using NHiberate.Mapping.Attributes rather than hbm files, so I need to be able to make alterations in the attributes of the Domain objects that will propagate to the hbm.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [lazy properties](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2010/01/27/nhibernate-new-feature-lazy-properties.aspx) IN NHibernate 3 to accomplish this. I assume, but don't know, that you can set that using attributes.